# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: output.json

Tags: python, pip

I am new to python. Would like to install pycontractions. But when I install using pip with the command pip install pycontractions, I got the error message below:

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpdcqyn4bl\output.json'

Can anyone help me on this?

I have tried clear the temporary files using the Disk Cleanup utility. I have tried upgrade pip by command pip install --upgrade pip.

Comment: https://github.com/ian-beaver/pycontractions/issues/26

Comment: @phd, I have tried download the language-check sources and pycontractions sources and installing from those local files using pip install -e, but I am still getting the same error